# Getting the role ID from the global $user

Tags: users

I'm very new to Drupal, so please bear with me if this is a dumb question. According to the [globals API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/user/6), the global `$user` object returns roles as an array:

```
[roles] => Array(
  [rid] => name
)
```

If I reference $user->roles, it gives me the role names.

Short of looping through like this:

```
foreach($user->roles as $key => $value){
    error_log("key: " . $key . " ; value: " . $value);
}
```

Is there any way to return the role ID (rid) instead of the role name? I need to do conditional processing based on roles, but some of our roles are company-specific, and contain special characters. It would be much easier to work with the ID instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to do this:

```
$rid = 42;

if (array_key_exists($rid, $user->roles)) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

If you just want an array of RIDs, you can use [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$rids = array_keys($user->roles);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$rid = 42;
if(isset($user->roles[$rid])) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

is what I usually use.  Same basic principle, even more basic coding.

```
array_keys($someArray)
```

as **Mark Trapp** cites is really useful for hunting through the keys of the many huge arrays that Drupal produces - e.g., the $fields variable in views templates - dumping the whole thing creates a mess, with just the keys you can usually figure out which element it is you need, and then just dump that.

For dumping variables, be sure to check out [Drupal for Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) - makes huge, unwieldy dumps nicely & elegantly separated from your HTML.